# Detecting an ellipse in a glaucoma photo

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ellipse, model-fitting, drawellipse

For glaucoma diagnosis it is common to determine a "cup to disk ratio" which compares the diameter of the optic disk (VDD) and optic cup (VCD). The optical disk is visible as a circular red feature (red channel) and the optic cup shows up as a yellow circle (green channel). How can I calculate the diameter ratio between optic disk and optic cup?

I am able to detect the optic disk with canny edge detection, but I have not found a way to calculate the cup to disk ratio. How might I do that?

Original image:

[image]

VDD and VCD:

[image]

Comment: could you upload a new image in which you clearly show what are the VDD and VCD please? thanks

Comment: @Benoit_11 sure, of course.

Comment: @Benoit_11 http://i.stack.imgur.com/kA8me.jpg. this link

Comment: For reference here is the question asked over at Mathematica.SE, before the user said they wanted MATLAB code: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99578/detecting-an-ellipse-in-a-glaucoma-photo

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with the terms you mentioned. Pls check whether the following code works for you.

```
clc; clear all;

img = imread('vu4TL.jpg');

imgr = img(:,:,1);
imshow(imgr);
imgrb = im2bw(imgr,.99);

se = strel('disk',2);
imgrbc = imclose(imgrb,se);

[cr, rr] = imfindcircles(imgrbc,[4 100],'ObjectPolarity', ...
    'bright','Sensitivity',0.92);

imgr = img(:,:,2);
imgrb = im2bw(imgr,.99);

se = strel('disk',2);
imgrbc = imclose(imgrb,se);

[cg, rg] = imfindcircles(imgrbc,[4 100],'ObjectPolarity', ...
    'bright','Sensitivity',0.92);

imshow(img);
hr = viscircles(cr,rr);
hb = viscircles(cg,rg);

cdr = rr/rg;

fprintf('\ncdr = %f\n', cdr);
```

Answer:

```
cdr = 2.225866
```

Output image:

[image]

Comment: de ni . thankyou for your code. i will try it. hope it can work